# design a weave in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6

[image]

How can i design that in photoshop? I don't even know it's name. Is that a weave effect ? Please help me.

Comment: [Click here for reasons why your question may have been down voted or placed on hold.](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2632/why-was-my-question-downvoted-and-or-closed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Rectangle Tool` to draw a rectangular path

[image: rectangle]
[image: rectangle]

Then use the `Direct Selection Tool` (the white one) to drag the corner point to where you want it - hold SHIFT while you do.

[image: direct]
[image: moved]

Now use the `Convert Point Tool` to drag your points' handles to where you would like them to be, creating the curves

[image: convert]
[image: curved]

Voila

[image: final]